# Maven install missing artifacts

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

When I make maven clean/install I obtain this error :

### Missing:

1) org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.0.1

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven -DartifactId=maven-archiver -Dversion=2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven -DartifactId=maven-archiver -Dversion=2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0
    2) org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.0.1

2) org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.codehaus.plexus -DartifactId=plexus-utils -Dversion=1.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.codehaus.plexus -DartifactId=plexus-utils -Dversion=1.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0
    2) org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4

---

2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  NexusMirror (http://x.x.x.x:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/)

Has anyone an idea on how to solve this?

Thank you in andvace

Comment: Can you post the full error output?

Comment: Thank you, today, when I reopened my pc it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That artifact exists and is available from Maven Central ([org.apache.maven.maven-archiver 2.0.1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.0.1/)). Your Nexus Mirror is misconfigured. You should investigate through the Nexus web interface and see why it's not fetching that artifact from the Central repository.